# React Native & TypeScript : Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'RefObject<TextInput>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

That's what I am doing:

```
  declare passCodeInput:  React.RefObject<TextInput>;
```

But here's an issue that I am getting while trying to call `focus` method:

```
setTimeout(() => this.passCodeInput.focus());
```

[image]

I call `focus` on `current`, like, `this.passCodeInput.current!.focus())` but this won't work in my case.

Comment: could you try this one 
**ref?.current?.focus()**

Comment: @Byka doesn't work for me

Answer (score -1):

You can use ref like below:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
...


const MyFormComponent = () => {

  const ref_input2 = useRef();
  const ref_input3 = useRef();

  return (
    <>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Input1"
        autoFocus={true}
        returnKeyType="next"
        onSubmitEditing={() => ref_input2.current.focus()}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Input2"
        returnKeyType="next"
        onSubmitEditing={() => ref_input3.current.focus()}
        ref={ref_input2}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Input3"
        ref={ref_input3}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: I am using Class Components:) and can't access `focus` on `current`

Comment: check this one https://www.javatpoint.com/react-refs#:~:text=When%20the%20ref%20attribute%20is,component%20as%20its%20current%20property.